# JS: Storing a function as a variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand storing a function as a variable.  If I have the following function:

```
function calc() {

     return 2 * 2 

}

calc() //returns 4

var test = calc() 

test // returns 4
```

I know that the variable `test` has the value of 4, which makes sense.

However, in this example:

```
  function foo() {

     console.log("HEY")

  }

 foo() //logs "HEY" in the console

 var test = foo() 

 test // does NOT log "HEY" in the console.
```

Why does that not follow the same pattern?

Comment: The `test` variable doesn’t store a function in either example. You’re just storing the return value of them. `calc` returns `4`, `foo` returns nothing. Neither return value could log anything.

Comment: `test` doesn't return 4, it *is* 4

Comment: The only way you can make `test` log anything on its own is with a global getter, i.e. `Object.defineProperty(globalThis, "test", { get(){ console.log("HEY"); } });`, which you probably don’t want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`var test = foo()` does not store the function `foo` into the variable `test`, it stores the *return value* of `foo` in test, and since `foo` doesn't specify a return value, the value stored in `test` will be `undefined`.

Further explanation: Placing parentheses after a function name or a reference to a function will call that function. To just reference the function without calling it, simply don't use parentheses until you're ready to call it. For example:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("HEY")
}

foo() // "HEY"

var test = foo; // no () here

test() // use () here. "HEY"
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function foo() {

     console.log("HEY")

  }

 foo() //logs "HEY" in the console

//correct way
// foo() is calling the function and asigning its return value
// foo is the function
 var test = foo 
 
 //then we call the stored function
 test()
```

Answer (score 0):

it's about **returning** and **doing** something!

when you call below fn, it's returning a value

```
var calc = function () { return 2*2; }
```

if you call this, it's doing something!

```
var foo = function () { console.log("hey"); }
```

that means, when you call calc fn, you need to assign it a variable

```
var result = calc();
```

if you want to log something, you just call foo (not assign)

```
foo(); // log appears on the fly

var bar = foo(); // log appears again but since foo is not return something bar will be nothing

// assign fn to variable, so now you can call variable!
bar = foo; // no log, wait for the call
bar(); // log appears!
```

Answer (score 0):

() calls the function and returns a value, so the brackets need to be  var test = foo
test()

Answer (score -1):

```
// This does the console.log as soon as it is called - it does not store the response and wait until a later time.
function foo() {
    console.log("hey"); 
}

// If you wanted to console.log something when you assign the variable, you can do this:
function foo() {
    return "hey";
}
var test = foo();

console.log('test: ', test);

// or this:
function foo() {
    return "hey";
}
var test = console.log(foo());
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to do: return "hey"; instead of console.log(hey);

Comment: This also wouldn’t log anything.

Comment: @Xufox It would in a REPL